# installing logstash plugin gives connection refused

Tags: logstash

I have elasticsearch 5.5.1 installed and running. I'm now trying to install logstash and required plugins to use against SQL Server. I'm trying to install the `logstash-input-jdbc` plugin but when I run the logstash plugin installer from powershell as admin (this is on windows server 2012 r2) I receive the following error:

**unable to download data from https://rubygems.org - Errno::ECONNREFUSED: connection refused - connection refused (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)**

So I went to github and downloaded the plugin leaving it in it's zip form in my C:\downloads folder.

I then ran `.\logstash-plugin install file:///C:/downloads/logstash-input-jdbc-master` and this time I get an error stating that it cant find the file

if I add the file extension .zip to the end of the command I then get:

**ERROR:Invalid pack for : file:///C:/downloads/logstash-input-jdbc-master.zip, reason: The pack must contain at least one plugin, message: The pack must contain at least one plugin**

Comment: The jdbc input plugin _should_ already be included in the default installation of logstash, so it _should_ not be necessary to install it.

Comment: It you want to add another plugin, you have to create a plugin pack, then install the plugin pack (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/offline-plugins.html#building-offline-packs))

Comment: @baudsp I cant see any plugins in the logstash directory. On the elastic forum I've been told that If I want to install the plugin in the second way (from a local file) I need to create a ruby server first and do it from there. I think that's a bit overkill for what I need so I'm hoping the connection refused is from our organisations firewall or similar and currently have them looking into it.

Comment: @baudsp basically I'm quite new to the ELK stack. I have downloaded and unzipped logstash. I have installed the SQLserver jdbc files I have created a logstash.conf file and now this is the plugin that I need before I attempt to run logstash for the first time.

Comment: I've never used used the jdbc input plugin, but the plugins that are already with logstash are in the folder logstash-5.5.0\vendor\bundle\jruby\1.9\gems. So I think you just have to launch logstash with your configuration file and see what it does.

Comment: @baudsp Ah....I can see one in there, but it looks to be 4.2.1  the SQL jdbc files that I downloaded are 6.2.1

Comment: I don't think there will be a problem if there is a version mismatch, they are two unrelated project (in the documentation they are using the 5.1.36 version, [see](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_usage))

Comment: @baudsp I just tried to run `logstash -f logstash.conf` using powershell and I get an error about an invalid URI in conf/log4j2.properties file I've not touched anything in this file as I've seen no documentation on it.

Comment: I've found the documentation on logging [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/logging.html). I never experienced a problem regarding this, but apparently it's a common problem if you have installed logstash in a Program Files location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@baudsp Helped me here. Yes, it definitely didn't work placing logstash under program files. Moving it out to it's own directory at root allowed logstash to run. Strange behavior. Credit for this answer goes to @baudsp